# Control the solving strategy of Z3

Tags: z3, smt, equation-solving

So lets assume I have a large Problem to solve in Z3 and if i try to solve it in one take, it would take too much time. So i divide this problem in parts and solve them individually.
As a toy example lets assume that my complex problem is to solve those 3 equations:

```
eq1: x>5
eq2: y<6
eq3: x+y = 10
```

So my question is whether for example it would be possible to solve eq1 and eq2 first. And then using the result solve eq3.

```
assert eq1
assert eq2

(check-sat)

assert eq3
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

seems to work but I m not sure whether it makes sense performancewise?
Would incremental solving maybe help me out there? Or is there any other feature of z3 that i can use to partition my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problems considered are usually satisfiability problems, i.e., the goal is to find *one* solution (model). A solution (model) that satisfies `eq1` does not necessarily satisfy `eq3`, thus you can't just cut the problem in half. We would have to find *all* solutions (models) for `eq1` so that we can replace `x` in `eq3` with that (set of) solutions. (For example, this is what happens in Gaussian elimination after the matrix is diagonal.)